# Can't get IPMI sensor data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, munin, ipmi

I have SuperMicro 1U 6016T-MTHF with Winbond WPCM450 BMC server. Here's my problem:

```
root@foo:~# ipmitool -I open sensor
FAN 1            | 8281.000   | RPM        | ok    | 400.000   | 576.000   | 784.000   | 33856.000 | 34225.000 | 34596.000
FAN 2            | 9216.000   | RPM        | ok    | 400.000   | 576.000   | 784.000   | 33856.000 | 34225.000 | 34596.000
FAN 3            | 9216.000   | RPM        | ok    | 400.000   | 576.000   | 784.000   | 33856.000 | 34225.000 | 34596.000
FAN 4            | 8281.000   | RPM        | ok    | 400.000   | 576.000   | 784.000   | 33856.000 | 34225.000 | 34596.000
FAN 5            | na         | RPM        | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN 6            | na         | RPM        | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
CPU1 Vcore       | 0.864      | Volts      | ok    | 0.776     | 0.800     | 0.824     | 1.352     | 1.376     | 1.400
CPU2 Vcore       | na         | Volts      | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
CPU1 DIMM        | 1.520      | Volts      | ok    | 1.288     | 1.312     | 1.336     | 1.656     | 1.680     | 1.704
CPU2 DIMM        | na         | Volts      | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
+5 V             | 5.120      | Volts      | ok    | 4.416     | 4.448     | 4.480     | 5.536     | 5.568     | 5.600
+5VSB            | 5.088      | Volts      | ok    | 4.416     | 4.448     | 4.480     | 5.536     | 5.568     | 5.600
+12 V            | 12.137     | Volts      | ok    | 10.600    | 10.653    | 10.706    | 13.250    | 13.303    | 13.356
-12 V            | -12.680    | Volts      | ok    | -13.650   | -13.456   | -13.262   | -10.546   | -10.352   | -10.158
VTT              | 1.112      | Volts      | ok    | 0.808     | 0.816     | 0.824     | 1.320     | 1.336     | 1.352
+3.3VCC          | 3.312      | Volts      | ok    | 2.880     | 2.904     | 2.928     | 3.648     | 3.672     | 3.696
+3.3VSB          | 3.264      | Volts      | ok    | 2.880     | 2.904     | 2.928     | 3.648     | 3.672     | 3.696
VBAT             | 3.168      | Volts      | ok    | 2.880     | 2.904     | 2.928     | 3.648     | 3.672     | 3.696
CPU1 Temp        | 0x0        | discrete   | 0x0000| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
CPU2 Temp        | 0x7        | discrete   | 0x0700| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
System Temp      | 29.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -9.000    | -7.000    | -5.000    | 75.000    | 77.000    | 79.000
P1-DIMM1A        | 35.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -9.000    | -7.000    | -5.000    | 65.000    | 70.000    | 75.000
P1-DIMM2A        | 37.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -9.000    | -7.000    | -5.000    | 65.000    | 70.000    | 75.000
P1-DIMM3A        | 38.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -9.000    | -7.000    | -5.000    | 65.000    | 70.000    | 75.000
P2-DIMM1A        | na         | degrees C  | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
P2-DIMM2A        | na         | degrees C  | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
P2-DIMM3A        | na         | degrees C  | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
Chassis Intru    | 0x0        | discrete   | 0x0000| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
PS Status        | 0x1        | discrete   | 0x01ff| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
```

Here I can see 'VTT' sensor, but this command fails:

```
root@foo:~# ipmitool -I open sensor get VTT
Locating sensor record...
Sensor data record "VTT" not found!
```

All other sensors work fine. Any Ideas why that single sensor is not working?

Comment: why not like: ipmitool -I open sensor |grep 'VTT'

Comment: Because I have munin script that parses this data. I'll have to rewrite it to use that command. Also it's writed in python and I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

On my system the sensor is called System VTT and doesn't work either... byt when I put space after VTT it works - it can be the same trick on yours :-)

```
# ipmitool -I open sensor|grep VTT
System VTT       | 1.137      | Volts      | ok    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
```

```
ipmitool -I open sensor get 'System VTT'
Locating sensor record...
Sensor data record "System VTT" not found!
```

doesn't work but:

```
ipmitool -I open sensor get 'System VTT '
Locating sensor record...
Sensor ID              : System VTT  (0x8f)
 Entity ID             : 3.6
 Sensor Type (Analog)  : Voltage
 Sensor Reading        : 1.137 (+/- 0) Volts
 Status                : ok
 Lower Non-Recoverable : na
 Lower Critical        : na
 Lower Non-Critical    : na
 Upper Non-Critical    : na
 Upper Critical        : na
 Upper Non-Recoverable : na
 Event Status          : Event Messages Disabled
 Assertion Events      : 
 Event Enable          : Event Messages Disabled
 Assertions Enabled    : unc-
```

does work as expected.